# Knitr 'asis' option not working when R produces LaTeX code

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I am running a process where I automatically produce a report. It has worked up until a point. But now `knitr::opts_chunk$set(result='asis')` does not work when I `cat` LaTeX code into the document. It replaces the `\` with `\textbackslash{}` when I `knit` the document. Even though if you run the `cat` command on its own, it produces the correct `LaTeX` code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "October 15, 2017"
output: pdf_document
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, comment = NA, background = NA, results='asis')
```

```{r}
cat("
  \\begin{tabular*}{1\\textwidth}{c c}
  \\parbox[c]{0.4\\linewidth}{
    {\\HUGE{\\textcolor{blue}{\\textbf{\\uppercase{Headline}}} }}\\\\
    \\Large{{\\textsc{Example}}}\\\\
  }&
    \\parbox{0.25\\textwidth}{
      \\icontext{MapMarker}{12}{Global}\\\\
      \\icontext{MobilePhone}{12}{999 666 23}\\\\
      \\icontext{Send}{12}{someemail@gmail.com}\\\\
    }
  \\end{tabular*}")
```
````

The error being produced:

[image]

I have tried using `knitr::asis_output()`, but it results in the same error

The `Tex` being produced is the following:

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\textbackslash{}begin\{tabular\emph{\}\{1\textwidth\}\{c c\}
\parbox[c]{0.4\linewidth}{
    {\HUGE{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\uppercase{Headline}}} }}\\
    \Large{{\textsc{Example}}}\\
  }\& \parbox{0.25\textwidth}{
      \icontext{MapMarker}{12}{Glogab}\\
      \icontext{MobilePhone}{12}{999 666 23}\\
      \icontext{Send}{12}{someemail@gmail.com}\\
    } \textbackslash{}end\{tabular}\}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show the generated tex file?

Comment: I thought at first it might be the `*`, but even if I remove it, the error keeps on occurring at other sections of the code.

Comment: Have you posted a bug report to knitr yet

Comment: It is a known Pandoc issue: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2493 (your issue looks different but I believe essentially it is the same: Pandoc cannot parse your raw TeX code so it escaped all special characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is finally a solution to these issues:

```
knitr::raw_latex("here all your tex content") 

instead of cat() + results='asis'.
```

https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1622

Comment: Deserves more than 1 up mark here.  Wish I could down vote `Rmarkdown` in general.  These workarounds are accumulating so that it is more difficult than `LaTeX`

Comment: Rmarkdown and pandoc are best working for html, indeed. Bringing complex latex commands to it is not a natural way to use Rmarkdown.